# I would like to Count how many records in my database have the same values in 3 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to COUNT how many records in my database have the same Title, the same User_ID and happened on the same day.

```
Table_01:
    ------------------------------------------
    EVENT_DATE              | Title | User_ID
    ------------------------------------------
    2014-08-28 00:00:00.000 | #0001 | 1111
    2014-08-28 00:00:00.000 | #0001 | 1113
    2014-08-28 00:00:00.000 | #0001 | 1113
    2014-08-30 00:00:00.000 | #0001 | 1111
    2014-08-03 00:00:00.000 | #0002 | 1111
    2014-08-28 00:00:00.000 | #0001 | 1111
    2014-08-15 00:00:00.000 | #0002 | 1111
    2014-08-28 00:00:00.000 | #0004 | 1112
    2014-08-30 00:00:00.000 | #0001 | 1111
    2014-08-02 00:00:00.000 | #0001 | 1111
    2014-08-28 00:00:00.000 | #0004 | 1112
    2014-08-01 00:00:00.000 | #0003 | 1111


------------------------------------------
EVENT_DATE              | Title | User_ID
------------------------------------------
2014-08-28 00:00:00.000 | #0001 | 1111
2014-08-28 00:00:00.000 | #0001 | 1111

2014-08-28 00:00:00.000 | #0001 | 1113
2014-08-28 00:00:00.000 | #0001 | 1113

2014-08-30 00:00:00.000 | #0001 | 1111
2014-08-30 00:00:00.000 | #0001 | 1111

2014-08-28 00:00:00.000 | #0004 | 1112
2014-08-28 00:00:00.000 | #0004 | 1112

2014-08-03 00:00:00.000 | #0002 | 1111
2014-08-15 00:00:00.000 | #0002 | 1111
2014-08-02 00:00:00.000 | #0001 | 1111
2014-08-01 00:00:00.000 | #0003 | 1111
```

So the answer would be 4, I don't need the details just the count.

Microsoft SQL Server 2016. Compatibility level: SQL Server 2005 (90)

Comment: @DanBracuk This is a reason to downvote, not a reason to close.

Comment: If you need a help to fix your code, then show that code, please. If you need to write a code, then this is not a good place to ask.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you just want two levels of aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from (select EVENT_DATE, Title, User_ID, count(*) as cnt
      from table_01
      group by EVENT_DATE, Title, User_ID
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: maybe just inner query is enough?

Comment: @LONG . . . "The answer would be 4".

Comment: @GordonLinoff - do we know that all timestamps are at midnight?  Probably want to cast to a date type.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I see, thx xD

Comment: @Hogan . . . I was going by the sample data in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to count all rows with at least 1 duplicate event_date, title and user_id:

```
select count(*) from (
    select row_number() over (partition by event_date, title, user_id) rn
    from mytable
) t where rn = 2
```